# How to deploy Angular @nrwl/nest application api to VM (server)?

Tags: angular, nestjs

I took the angular @nrwl/nest application build.I get 2 file(main.js and main.js.map) inside of dist/app folder. I didn't get any index file.So I don't know how to deploy the server. Please help me.

Note: I am using Angular NX.

Comment: How did you build your application? What command did you run? `ng build --prod api`? Or whatever your server project is named in the `angular.json`. You don't need to have an `index.js` file, you just need to tell `node` what file to run (in this case it would be like `node dist/api/main.js` (or switch out api for your server's project name)

Comment: Hey Jay, Thank you so much for your answer. I thing I will deploy to nest.js host (firebase). Right?